# Encrypt single file in apfs

Tags: macos, apfs

APFS supports single-key and multi-key encryption, for the full filesystem and for individual files. Is it possible to encrypt a single file or folder without encrypting the entire drive on macOS High Sierra 10.13.6 with APFS?